# Using Parse arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, swifty-json

I have a parse.com array in the form ["2","4","6","8"]. When I retrieve my array it is in JSON. I am using swiftyJSON. Error I am getting at runtime is dynamic type cast failed. Here is my code. My parse.com array name is Options

```
 if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                    let pf = object as PFObject
                    let name = pf["Question"] as String
                   // let data1 = pf["Options"] as? NSData
                    let jsonData: NSData = pf["Options"] as NSData
                    let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
                    self.myArray = json.arrayObject as Array<String>
                    println(name)
                    self.question.text = name


                   // println(answers1)
                }
            }
```

Comment: When is the table reloading? It has just 1 row with no text?

Comment: Number of rows is answers.count . It is working well with static arrays

Comment: so I'm not clear what the problem is, explain what isn't working in more detail and show the associated code

Comment: presumably you don't get `NSData`, you get `NSString` so it can't be cast/converted